# android navigation clear task

Tags: android, navigation, android-architecture-navigation

I'm using The new Navigation Architecture Component in android. 
I have three fragment, LoginFragment, MainFragment, SettingFragment. Host fragment is LoginFragment, when login success, go to MainFragment, in MainFragment to go SettingFragment and log out go to LoginFragment.

How can I clear task(MainFragment and SettingFragment) when I log out?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Pop Behavior** in nav graph and set **Pop To**, This removes fragments from top of the stack until the id of the fragment you specified.

You can check out this [article](https://android.jlelse.eu/navigation-controller-an-android-storyboard-4dd7229ca821) for more details or [this](https://proandroiddev.com/android-navigation-component-tips-tricks-implementing-splash-screen-f0f5ce046a09).

Answer (score 0):

***Put this code***

```
FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
for(int i = 0; i < fm.getBackStackEntryCount(); ++i) {    
    fm.popBackStack();
}
```

**But could equally have used something like:**

```
FragmentManager.popBackStack(String name, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE)
```